# как остановить условие?

Tags: javascript

Есть условие, которое добавляет новый li, мне нужно, чтобы после того как количество li превысило 8 новые li не создавались, т.е прервать условие.

```
  btn_Hobbies.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (input_Hobbies.value.length > 0) {
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.innerHTML = input_Hobbies.value;
      list.insertBefore(newLi, list.children[0]);
}

});
```

Comment: что такое counter?

Comment: я подправил и убрал его. его нету, это были мои размышления.

Answer (score 1):

```js
btn_Hobbies.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (input_Hobbies.value.length > counter) {
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = input_Hobbies.value;
    list.insertBefore(newLi, list.children[0]);
    counter++;
    if (counter > 8) return;
  }

});
```